# How to get project name of file in visual studio add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I try to create an add-in which you can make some operations on file you work on (.cs and .aspx files)

I want to access project name of that file.

I tried these codes but I can't find what I want.

```
_applicationObject.Solution.FullName.ToString()
_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.FullName.ToString()
_applicationObject.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName.ToString()

Projects projects = _applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects as Projects;
Project project = null;
if (projects != null)
{
    if (projects.Count > 0)
    {
        project = projects.Item(0);
    }
}
Clipboard.SetText(project.UniqueName);
```

Comment: Check this : http://uisurumadushanka89.blogspot.in/2013/04/visual-studio-extensibility-get-active.html

Comment: it's not working. project name is null when I call that method.

Comment: navigate to your main solution path and open .csproj file as an xml file and read it? doesn't work? There is a PropertyGroup Xml Node where you should be able to get the info you need. Visual Studio is doing the same i suppose

Comment: yeah, the project name is stored in either the solution or the project file, so if you can get to the solution or the project filename, just read that file as plain xml.

Answer (score 0):

Name of the project is not a thing that stored in the project description. You need to locate the project file. Name of the project file without the extension is the project name.

If you want to access root namespace or assembly name that's another thing, let me know and I'll explain it.